# How to open all emails in a utf8 encode?

Tags: php, email, utf-8

Below is my code that I open "Zoho" to get unread emails.

The problem is that the encoding from emails coming from Gmail and Outlook are different. 
Gmail is utf-8 and Outlook (live) is iso-8869-7.

How to handle this?

```
$hostname = '{imappro.zoho.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'email@email.com';
$password = 'password';


/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username ,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Zoho: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
```

Comment: Sigh. MS and character encoding. Always a horror trip, Microsoft never gets that right... You would need to convert the encoding of all content yourself, but that is not easy, since PHP does not really offer any reliable method to do so. That is not a fault of php, actually, it is a general issue, since there is no "correct" way of doing so. You want to look into the `iconv?? extension for php: http://php.net/manual/de/book.iconv.php

Comment: Note that you can _not_ rely on the autodetection of encoding, that is unreliable and notoriously famous for delivering false results. You need to _know_ what encoding a given text has, since it is theoretically impossible to detect that in most cases.

Comment: @arkascha thank you for your valuable info. But there must be a way, I mean how people do this in general? For sure iconv is not the best solution at all.

Comment: I would expect that you can somehow tell the MS Outlook service to use unicode as all other services do.